# Can I write generic music in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I have the same notes for two instruments (small and big drums: tommh and tomfh).
Is it possible to write a "generic" voice and use that for the two instruments with different notes (tommh and tommfh)?

```
\version "2.22.1"

\score {
        \new StaffGroup <<
          \new DrumStaff << \new DrumVoice = "Klein" \drummode { tommh4 tommh4 tommh4 tommh4 } >>
          \new DrumStaff << \new DrumVoice = "Gross" \drummode { tomfh4 tomfh4 tomfh4 tomfh4 } >>
        >>
}
```

I want to have something like this:

```
\version "2.22.1"

generic = \drummode { x4 x4 x4 x4 }

\score {
        \new StaffGroup <<
          \new DrumStaff << \new DrumVoice = "Klein" \drummode \generic[tommh] >>
          \new DrumStaff << \new DrumVoice = "Gross" \drummode \generic[tomfh] >>
        >>
}
```

Comment: It’s not my expertise, but I would guess that a Scheme function can do that.